# Recyclerview elevation progressively changes when scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-elevation

I have a `recyclerview`, which i've added a `elevation` to. It seems that elevation gets higher depending on where on the screen the item is located vertically, the shadow grows as the item gets scrolled down. I've tried adding a background color, which has not helped. I found another post with a video showing the problem. https://youtu.be/nROYq8rpUMs

**Here's my relativelayout where I add the elevation.**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#EDEDED"
    android:focusable="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/newsRowRelativeLayout"
    android:elevation="4dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/newsImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxHeight="300dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@color/mainTextBGColor" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newsTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_below="@id/newsType"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/news_title"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_margin"
        android:textSize="@dimen/news_title_main" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newsType"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_below="@id/newsImage"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/mainBGColor"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_margin"
        android:textSize="@dimen/news_tag_detailed" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newsText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/newsTitle"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:textColor="@color/news_text"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_margin"
        android:textSize="@dimen/news_text_main"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with it. The Elevation effect uses a so called **Key-Light** and **Ambient-Light**. One sits right above the screen (Ambient-Light), the other one (Key-Light) with a 45° angle above the screen. That's why the shadow is moving while you're scrolling.

**tl;dr**
The shadow is not static but dynamically calculated. See also the following picture explaining the concept:

[image: material design shadows concept]

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Interesting. So there is no way for me to create the same shadow effect for each recyclerview item? I thought the elevation worked a little different so thats why I didn't think about something like that. Thanks!

Comment: At least not with the elevation property. Before `Material Design` was introduced people were basically using "fake" `CardViews` with a `layer-list` background. Naturally this generated a static background image with a static shadow but I wouldn't recommend going for that approach.

Comment: Dang. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not posting the final solution, but the draft I'm working on.

I understand the theory of Android's elevation, but it doesn't make any sense to me, so my idea is to listen the scroll of the contents on screen and adapt the elevation based on that.

```
public class VerticalScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

    int[] visible = new int[1];
    mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPositions(visible);
    int[] lastvisible = new int[1];
    mLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPositions(lastvisible); 
    for (int i = visible[0]; i<lastvisible[0]; i++){
      RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i);
     int[] location = new int[2];
     ((MessageViewHolder)viewHolder).contentView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
     float y = location[1];
     float ratio = y/scheight;
     ((MessageViewHolder)viewHolder).contentView.setElevation(16-14*ratio);
    }

}

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int newState) {
    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
}}
```